# Extract data from oracle hyperion essbase

Tags: oracle, hyperion, essbase

How can I extract data from oracle hyperion essbase with command via vpn client ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to consider. The fact that it's on VPN doesn't really matter, but obviously your machine needs to be able to communicate with the Essbase server. The simplest approach would be to use the MaxL interpreter. MaxL is the scripting language that ships with Essbase. It is installed on Essbase servers but would need to be installed locally to your machine in order for you to extract data. The MaxL scripting language would give you the ability to run an Essbase report script (this is a script language that outputs data in a defined format), run an MDX script (MDX is like Essbase's equivalent of SQL), run a calc script that exports data, or just export all of the data in the cube using the appropriate MaxL command (this can end up generating very large files though).

You will need to do some amount of work to properly define a report script or MDX script and execute it, but the Essbase technical reference will help immensely.

Comment: Does the MaxL interepreter give me the hand to see all the cubes in oracle at first time. I need to see all the cubes at the beginning then I select the cube of which I want to load its data

Comment: MaxL can be used to list the applications and cubes. You would then use one of those application/cube names to create an additional script that will extract data. Note that MaxL is used to both extract data from the cube and load data to the cube, if needed. It sounds like you would greatly benefit from learning more about how Essbase works so you can figure out what your options are.

Comment: ok, I am doing. My problem is how can I use MaxL from my windows pc with command prompt to connect essbase and load its cubes

Comment: I need to export database from essbase server  to my local pc , How can  do it ? the export command download the file on the server. Or how can I download the result file from the server